# laravel read data from database returning duplicate result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to read data from MySql with "Laravel 5.3". Then I serve them using json.

Here is my code:

```
public function getUserTimeline(Request $request)
  {
    $input=$request->all();
    $id = Input::get('id');

    $usertimeline = DB::table('users') 
    ->join('timeline','users.id', '=', 'timeline.user_id')
    ->where('users.id',$id)
    ->get();
    return $usertimeline;
  }
```

But db returns duplicate data to me like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "0":1,
      "1":"Berkay Erdi",
      "2":"berkayerdi",
      "3":"berkayerdi@gmail.com",
      "id":1,
      "name":"Berkay Erdi",
      "username":"berkayerdi",
      "email":"berkayerdi@gmail.com"
   }
]
```

Bottom key-value datas are true one. I do not understand why are the data repeated. Is the error in the database? Or what else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `SELECT` clause in order for you to get your wanted results.

```
public function getUserTimeline(Request $request)
{
    $input=$request->all();
    $id = Input::get('id');

    $usertimeline = DB::table('users')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->join('timeline','users.id', '=', 'timeline.user_id')
        ->where('users.id',$id)
        ->get();
    return $usertimeline;
}
```

Please master the basics of PHP and SQL first before diving into any frameworks. Also read the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) thoroughly.